# Is it possible to maintain order of ngrams in the output of textcnt function in R?

Tags: r, n-gram

I am using the `textcnt()` function from `tau` package to obtain bigrams as follows:

```
sentence <- "A sample sentence in English for testing purpose"
english <- textcnt(sentence, method = "string", n=2, tolower = FALSE)
```

bigrams returned are in alphabetic order, like this:

```
 A sample     English for     for testing      in English sample sentence     sentence in testing purpose
```

However I am looking for a solution that could return the bigrams in the order as they appear in sentence. To be more exact the desired output is as follows:

```
 A sample  sample sentence sentence in  in English  English for  for testing   testing purpose
```

If it is not possible with `textcnt()` is there an alternate to acheive the desired output?

Comment: One alternative: `library(tidytext) ; data.frame(sentence) %>% unnest_tokens(ngram, sentence, token = 'ngrams', n = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(tokenizers)
tokenize_ngrams(sentence, n = 2L)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a sample"        "sample sentence" "sentence in"     "in english"      "english for"     "for testing"     "testing purpose"
```